# Why do I get a Communication problem... when I click on a button in a UI created after a Link was clicked in the previous UI?

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin

I have a strange "Communication problem" Vaadin error when I try to do the following:

I have two UIs, the first has a Link which points to another UI, here's the code:

```
public class MenuUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MenuUI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        layout.setSpacing(true);
        setContent(layout);

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

        MenuItem submenu1 = menuBar.addItem("Submenu 1", null);
        MenuItem submenu2 = menuBar.addItem("Submenu 2", null);

        submenu1.addItem("Option 1", null);
        submenu1.addItem("Option 2", null);

        submenu2.addItem("Option 3", null);
        submenu2.addItem("Option 4", new Command() {
            @Override
            public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {
                Notification.show("That was option 4");
            }
        });
        layout.addComponent(menuBar);

        Link link = new Link("Go to ShortcutKeys",
                             new ExternalResource(Page.getCurrent().getLocation().toString() + "Shortcut"));
        link.setTargetName("_blank");
        layout.addComponent(link);
    }

}
```

This UI results into this:
[image]

When I click on the Link, a ne UI is initialized, here is the code of the new UI:

```
public class ShortcutUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/Shortcut", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = ShortcutUI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        layout.setSpacing(true);
        setContent(layout);

        final TextField tf = new TextField("Your data:");
        layout.addComponent(tf);

        Button button = new Button("Send data (ENTER)");
        button.setClickShortcut(KeyCode.ENTER, ModifierKey.SHIFT);

        button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                layout.addComponent(new Label(tf.getValue()));
                tf.setValue("");
                tf.focus();
            }
        });

        layout.addComponent(button);
    }
```

This results into:

[image]

Here I type some text, and then when I click on the "Send data" Button, I get the following:

[image]

Why do I get this Communication problem? If the UI is not created from the clicked Link, i.e. for example if I had put the ShortcutUI init() content inside the MenuUI, like in the following class:

```
public class MenuUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MenuUI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        layout.setSpacing(true);
        setContent(layout);

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

        MenuItem submenu1 = menuBar.addItem("Submenu 1", null);
        MenuItem submenu2 = menuBar.addItem("Submenu 2", null);

        submenu1.addItem("Option 1", null);
        submenu1.addItem("Option 2", null);

        submenu2.addItem("Option 3", null);
        submenu2.addItem("Option 4", new Command() {
            @Override
            public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {
                Notification.show("That was option 4");
            }
        });
        layout.addComponent(menuBar);

        Link link = new Link("Go to ShortcutKeys",
                             new ExternalResource(Page.getCurrent().getLocation().toString() + "Shortcut"));
        link.setTargetName("_blank");
        layout.addComponent(link);

        // Shortcut Keys
        final TextField tf = new TextField("Your data:");
        layout.addComponent(tf);

        Button button = new Button("Send data (ENTER)");
        button.setClickShortcut(KeyCode.ENTER, ModifierKey.SHIFT);

        button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                layout.addComponent(new Label(tf.getValue()));
                tf.setValue("");
                tf.focus();
            }
        });

        layout.addComponent(button);
    }

}
```

The code would result into this:

[image]

All working as it should. No communication problem at all ("Some text" and "Some other text" are labels added when the click is performed on the "Send data" Button).

So Why if I have a UI created from a Link, a Click event fired on a Button causes this "Communication problem" in Vaadin?

This is the complete error as from ?debug Vaadin console:

```
Communication error: (SyntaxError) : Unexpected token < - Original JSON-text: html> 
<html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <meta 
http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;chrome=1" /> <style type="text/css">html, 
body {height:100%;margin:0;}</style> <link rel="shortcut icon" 
type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" 
href="./../../VAADIN/themes/chapter_4_menubar_and_shortcutkeys/favicon.ico" /> <link 
rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" 
href="./../../VAADIN/themes/chapter_4_menubar_and_shortcutkeys/favicon.ico" /> </head> 
<body scroll="auto" class=" v-generated-body"> <div id="Chapter4MenuBarandShortcutKeys-
1103734620" class=" v-app chapter_4_menubar_and_shortcutkeys"> <div class=" v-app-
loading"></div> <noscript> You have to enable javascript in your browser to use an  
application built with Vaadin. </noscript> </div> <script type="text/javascript" 
src="./../../VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">//<!
[CDATA[ if (!window.vaadin) alert("Failed to load the bootstrap javascript: 
./../../VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js"); if (typeof window.__gwtStatsEvent != 'function') { 
vaadin.gwtStatsEvents = []; window.__gwtStatsEvent = function(event) 
{vaadin.gwtStatsEvents.push(event); return true;}; } 
vaadin.initApplication("Chapter4MenuBarandShortcutKeys-1103734620",{ "authErrMsg": { 
"caption": "Authentication problem", "message": "Take note of any unsaved data, and 
<u>click here<\/u> or press ESC to continue." }, "comErrMsg": { "caption": "Communication 
problem", "message": "Take note of any unsaved data, and <u>click here<\/u> or press ESC 
to continue." }, "debug": true, "heartbeatInterval": 300, "serviceUrl": "./../..", 
"sessExpMsg": { "caption": "Session Expired", "message": "Take note of any unsaved data, 
and <u>click here<\/u> or press ESC key to continue." }, "standalone": true, "theme": 
"chapter_4_menubar_and_shortcutkeys", "vaadinDir": "./../../VAADIN/", "versionInfo": 
{"vaadinVersion": "7.3.7"}, "widgetset": "com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" }); //]]></script> 
</body> </html
```

Why this happens?

Comment: Hey i have  exectly the same problem :( could you find out why ? Would help me ot allot uf you could give me an answer thx :)

Comment: @WarGodNT Check my answer below, hope it will help you too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few notes on how to resolve such an issue if someone comes across the same problem I faced.

The problem was the mapping of the VaadinServlet responsible for showing the ShortcutUI:

In a nutshell, this:

```
 @WebServlet(value = "/Shortcut", asyncSupported = true)
```

Should become this:

```
 @WebServlet(value = "/Shortcut/*", asyncSupported = true)
```

As when there are events fired on the ShortcutUI and send to the server, they are send with a request to an URL looking like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/Shortcut/UIDL/?v-uiId=0
```

If the application's context root is `/myapp`, or like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/Shortcut/UIDL/?v-uiId=0
```

If the application's context root is the DocumentRoot of the servlet container (e.g. in a Maven project created via the `mvn` command and ran with `mvn jetty:run` using the embedded Jetty).

That's why `/Shortcut` is never going to match against `/Shortcut/UIDL/?v-uiId=0`, hence the error. `Shortcut/*`, instead, will match, as "/*" after `Shortcut` will match `/UIDL/?v-uiId=0`.

Another important thing to note is that you might be tempted to modify the servlet mapping of your "entry point" UI (i.e. the UI mapped to `/*`) and change this:

`@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)`

To this:

`@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "", "/VAADIN/*" }, asyncSupported = true)`

**Definitely don't do that!** This will work until the Vaadin application makes a `/HEARTBEAT` request or an event on the user interface is fired and send to the server (making a "/UIDL" request). Vaadin still needs that "*" cause it is going to match against requests like this ("/HEARTBEAT", "/UIDL", and so on...).

So the unique solution for such a problem IMHO is to use:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
```

For `MenuUI`, and:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/Shortcut/*", asyncSupported = true)
```

For the `ShortcutUI`, and do the same for any "sub-UI" of the application, if multiple UIs are needed.

Otherwise, another option will be to use the `Navigator` API -> https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.navigator.html

Comment: Thank you allot for you HQ answer !